# Signing certificates

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle

i've got a little problem concerning signing of certificates. I'm using the .net bouncycastle api. I've generated a root-ca with open-ssl which i want to use for signing further certificates. 
My Problem is, that i cannot verify my generated certificates because open-ssl isn't able to read the files. Further investigation revealed, that the "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" as well as the "END CERTIFICATE" tags were missing within my files.

Open-SSL Error:
3900:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

The following code shows how i accomplish the generating process.

```
X509V3CertificateGenerator generator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
generator.SetSerialNumber(BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random()));
generator.SetIssuerDN(serverCertificate.SubjectDN);
generator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now);
generator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.Now.AddYears(5));
generator.SetSubjectDN(certificationRequestInfo.Subject);
generator.SetPublicKey(publicKey);
generator.SetSignatureAlgorithm("SHA512withRSA");
generator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.AuthorityKeyIdentifier, false, new     AuthorityKeyIdentifierStructure(serverCertificate));
generator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.SubjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifierStructure(publicKey));

var newClientCert = generator.Generate(kP.Private);

newClientCert.Verify(kP.Public); 
byte[] b = DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(newClientCert).Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
```

I would be very grateful for any hints or ideas..
kind regards

michael

Comment: Does it work if you just add those fixed markers? I know that's not a final solution, but it would help to know if that's the only problem.

Answer (score 3):

BouncyCastle C# has support in the Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl namespace for writing a certificate out in PEM format directly:

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = ...;
using (FileStream fs = ...)
{
    TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);
    PemWriter pw = new PemWriter(w);
    pw.WriteObject(cert);
    pw.Writer.Close();
}
```